# How to organize containers "horizontally" inside Kubernetes pods?

Tags: architecture, docker, kubernetes

So I'm trying to wrap my head around what exactly a typical Kubernetes pod looks like. According to [their docs](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/user-guide/pods.html), a *pod*:

> "*A pod (as in a pod of whales or pea pod) corresponds to a colocated group of applications running with a shared context.*"

Later in that same article:

> "*Pods can be used to host vertically integrated application stacks, but their primary motivation is to support co-located...*"

OK, so you *can* organize a single pod as your entire vertical stack (from DB to web app). But apparently that's not typically how it's organized, so I assume that typically a "*horizontal*" organization is preferred (**why??**).

But to me, horizontal layering/stratification implies that you'll only have one container in a pod, because typically in each tier of service (web, app, cache, db, etc.) you'll have one type of component.

Let's take a concrete example. Say we have the following vertical stack of tiers:

- Web frontend containers; Grails or Spring MVC web/app server
- Microservices containers; RESTful web services where core business logic lives
- Message broker (say RabbitMQ) containers
- Microservice cache (some services have distributed Hazelcast cache clusters sitting between them and their DB/backing store) containers
- MySQL DB cluster containers
- MongoDB cluster containers
- 3rd party RESTful cloud API (say SalesForce or Stripe or something similar)

These are fairly typical components in an app stack. If we went against Kubernetes' own advice, and created "vertically-aligned" pods, each pod would consist of 1 type of container for each tier (the web/app server, each microservice, each DB, etc.).

**But how would a horizontally-aligned pod be organized? What containers would go in which pods?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Pod is the basic scheduling unit in Kubernetes. It is the common case that a pod will only have a single container running in it, as most containers can be scheduled independently (i.e. they do not need to be co-located on the same machine).

With regards to your example, you could put most containers in individual pods, and use a **Replication Controller** to horizontally scale the number of replicas of each Pod (and therefore container) as needed. Along with your replication controller, you'll also want a **Service** to load balance between the replicas. Vertical tiers could be organized using labels on the pods/replication controllers/services, such as `tier=message_broker`.

*Edit:*

The reason it's not a good idea to put your entire stack in a single pod is it limits your flexibility:

- It forces your entire stack to be scheduled on a single machine, which could make scheduling more difficult if machines lack some of the necessary resources.
- Individual components cannot be scaled independently (e.g. if you need more frontend replicas to handle traffic, but your DB is only used for a small number of queries)
- All the containers would need to agree on which ports to use. Each pod has a unique IP, so containers running in separate pods can use the same ports.

Comment: Thanks @Tim St. Clair (+1) - starting to make sense now. Can you provide an example of this "*co-location*" (where you *would* put more than oe container type in a pod)? Thanks again!

Comment: Actually I think the text following your second quote from the [documentation](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/user-guide/pods.html#uses-of-pods) answers this. I think a common one is a log manager (for archiving, rotating, reporting, etc.) running alongside another service.